# Would there be monsoons in a planet without axial tilt?

Tags: science-based, climate

From what I've read, a planet without axial tilt wouldn't have seasons, at least the way we experience it today.

But from my understanding, monsoons are periodic inversions of the direction of the winds that occur due to the different warming rates between the earth and the sea.

Assuming a continent near the equator, with a big area and no mountains, would the heating of the land produce the low pressure necessary for a monsoon? If so, what would the periodicity of said monsoon be, since there would be no seasons as we know them? (assume that everything besides the axial tilt is earth-like)

Comment: Hi Pedro. This question doesn't seem to me to be about [the process itself of building a world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process), but rather about one part of the world you are building (specifically a part of its climate). Thus, I removed the worldbuilding-process tag from your question.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Still new on this site, please excuse my mistakes while I adapt. :)

Comment: No worries, we are all newcomers at some point! The Stack Exchange format can take some getting used to. (You seem to be doing quite well, all things considered.) If you are uncertain about a specific tag, you can read about its intended usage by looking it up on [the tags page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags) (also linked from the top of the page). If you are *still* uncertain, it's often best to leave it out; someone will edit it in if it's actually relevant to categorizing the question. Or, now that you have sufficient reputation, you can drop by in [chat] and ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because as you said:

> monsoons are periodic inversions of the direction of the winds that occur due to the different warming rates between the earth and the sea.

Unless another factor is added like a very elliptic orbit causing variation in the energy received from the star, or being in a binary star system for example, the temperatures will be very consistent overtime. Yet, the heating will create a consistent moderate low pressure system over the equatorial regions.